# how to put link as an additional column in display tag to redirect it to action class of struts2

Tags: struts2

i am displaying a object detail through display tag.
now i want a link in page through which user can delete or edit that particular record 
so i want a link which has object id as value and pass it to action class.
or any other way so that i can delete or edit perticular record
thank in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
<display:table name="sessionScope.searchResults"
    cellpadding="1" uid="sr" pagesize="50" cellspacing="1" size="50"
    defaultorder="ascending" sort="list" style="width:850"
     id="row">
    <display:column media="html"
    title="Delete"
    style="text-align:center">
    <s:url id="deleteUrl" action="deleteLink.action">
    <s:param name="objectId" value="#attr.row.OBJECT_ID" />
    </s:url>
    <s:a href="%{deleteUrl}">
         Delete
    </s:a>
</display:column>

</display:table>
```

**OBJECT_ID** is the ID of the current rows object, send the id to your action class load the obect with the id and do what ever you want to do.

You will get a hyper link on Delete image, Clicking on Delete will send you to **deleteLink.action**

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at display:column, you can use the href and paramId to pass unique id to the url to delete a particular record.